# Converting the HTML page to a downloadable PDF with a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to convert my HTML page to a PDF file with a button click. After I click this "Download" button, I want the PDF to be automatically downloaded.

I tried this:

```
<button onclick="printFunction()">Download</button>
<script>
      function printFunction() { 
        window.print(); 
      }
</script>
```

But this can only generate a print page, which I need to save the PDF file manually.

I searched online and find a lot of answers that suggest we add a third-party plug-in. Is there an easier way to do that?

I found a similar example here: https://phpcoder.tech/download-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript/

Comment: Using a third party plugin is the easier way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use html2pdf

```
<body id="body">
<button id="button">Click me!</button>

<script src="html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
const btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
var element = document.getElementById('body');
html2pdf().from(element).save('filename.pdf');
});
</script>
</body>
```

here are the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0
You can change filename.pdf to whatever you want (aside from the extension)

Comment: Thank you so much. I used this method, but the downloaded PDF is a blank file. How can I add the whole HTML page

Comment: I updated the awnser try that

Comment: I'm getting a blank PDF as well, using the script above.

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me:

```
<body id="body">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Function to handle download
    function downloadFunction() {
        hideButtons();
        const element = document.getElementById('body');
        const formattedDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB').replace(/\//g, '-');
        const options = {
            margin: 10,
            filename: 'FileName_' + formattedDate + '.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1.0 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 4 },
            jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
        };
        html2pdf(element, options);
        showButtons();
    }
</script>

<button onclick="downloadFunction()">Download this WebPage as PDF</button>

<p>
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
</p>

</body>
```

Source Document: https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/

CDN JS link: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html2pdf.js/0.10.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).